# "'Could not load file or assembly 'Elmah' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified'' after using Elmah.MVC in NuGet

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I have a MVC app, I used http://nuget.org/ to install Elmah for MVC, I Was able to install it and run it successively.

After few week reopening Visual Studio I Get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Elmah' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 


Error
<httpModules>
Line 73:       <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
```

I tried to add a reference in the project to Elmah.Mvc but with no success. Could you point me out how to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: I had this issue as well and solved it by setting "Copy Local" to true

Comment: Had similar error, turns out I was targeting the wrong configuration and had recently added ELMAH. The ELMAH DLLs were missing from my /bin folder and IIS was pointing to Debug root.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reinstall Elmah.Mvc via NuGet would be my advice. If this doesn't help, try reinstalling the elmah.corelibrary NuGet package (being a dependency of Elmah.Mvc).

Comment: Thanks for the hit, I have also added a reference in the project

Answer (score 0):

My project was using Elmah.Io.Log4Net.  I got the same error messages above "The system cannot find the file specified".  I installed Elmah.Io.Mvc 4.3.40 version and the error went away. So, the same problem happens in Elmah.Io that happens in the older Core version.