# Every time I switch git branches I end up missing DLL references (Elmah)

Tags: c#, dll, reference, elmah

This is my first time initializing a project and downloading it from a repo from another developer. When I try to inialize it. I am missing references. I have solved some references being missing by right clicking them in the reference tab Clicking Properties, and Enablying "Copy Local" to true... This has worked for others. But when I do this for this specific reference (Elmah) it keeps turning back to false. I also don't see a .DLL in the folder if I try to manually add it. It only shows a .nuget file. Can someone explain to me exactly how .nuget works when you first download your solution? How is it suppost to work- and can someone give me an idea as to why this might be failing? Here are some references thatI have tried that are failing. ["'Could not load file or assembly 'Elmah' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified'' after using Elmah.MVC in NuGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238561/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-elmah-or-one-of-its-dependencies-the-system)

This solution worked for this for my infrastructure .dll
[Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149851/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-web-infrastructure/32450500)

Whenever I try to simply reinstall Elmah from .nuget package manager I get the error

```
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Failed to add reference to 'Elmah'.
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

Comment: Is your gitignore ignoring dlls (most likely) ? You will need to make an exception for the you need

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved. I manually deleted it and simply reinstalled it after manually deleted it. I have yet to see if I switch branches if it will retain though.